# WPF ContentRendered event not firing?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple, but WPF is not something I generally work in, so I'm scratching my head a bit on this.

I am trying to show a "splash screen" for an application that is meant to run in the background.  It's basically a process wrapper for Windows operating systems.

I have a WPF `Window` defined as such:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Timer _timer;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ContentRendered += MainWindow_ContentRendered;
    }

    private void MainWindow_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(5000);
        _timer.Elapsed += TimerOnElapsed;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void TimerOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            Hide();
            Close();
        });

    }

    ~MainWindow()
    {
        _timer.Dispose();
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window, System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector {

    private bool _contentLoaded;

    /// <summary>
    /// InitializeComponent
    /// </summary>
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
    public void InitializeComponent() {
        if (_contentLoaded) {
            return;
        }
        _contentLoaded = true;
        System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/MySolution.WindowsWrapper;component/mainwindow.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);

        #line 1 "..\..\MainWindow.xaml"
        System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);

        #line default
        #line hidden
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Design", "CA1033:InterfaceMethodsShouldBeCallableByChildTypes")]
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Maintainability", "CA1502:AvoidExcessiveComplexity")]
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1800:DoNotCastUnnecessarily")]
    void System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector.Connect(int connectionId, object target) {
        this._contentLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

XAML looks like:

```
<Window x:Class="MySolution.WindowsWrapper.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MySolution.WindowsWrapper"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Splash" Height="100" Width="327" WindowStyle="None" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ShowInTaskbar="False" Topmost="True">
    <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="my-logo-large.png"/>
    </Window.Background>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

...in my Program.cs file, I have something like this:

```
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var splashScreen = new MainWindow();
        splashScreen.Show();

        SetupSystemTrayIcon();

        var showConsole = args.Any(x => x.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("showconsole"));
        StartService(showConsole);
        WaitToDie();
    }
```

The splash screen displays as expected... but the timer is never initialized, and never fires, so it never goes away.

From what I've read, the `ContentRendered` event is supposed to be fired when the window is shown... but that doesn't seem to happen.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: can show your xaml?

Comment: @tabby, I added it; very simple.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs could you please also add the second part of your `partial class MainWindow`(the part with `void System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector.Connect(int connectionId, object target)` method)

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov I don't see the second part of the partial class.  I can't seem to drill down to it either?  Maybe that's the problem?  Sorry, I'm not in my element here with WPF.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs if you create a WPF solution by default you will get `MainWindow.xaml`,`MainWindow.xaml .cs` and generated for them `public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window, System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector`. In which are implemented `Connect` and `InitializeComponent` methods. Maybe that is the part you are missing. Try to create WPF Solution and review that class.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov Ah, found it, added it to the OP.  That was not obvious.

Comment: Where is your Application object?

Comment: @mm8 if you are referring to the App.xaml, it's in the project, but empty except for the auto-generated code.  It's no longer the entry point though, I made a Program.cs file and used its Main().

Comment: You are not creating an Application object with a dispatcher in your main method...and what does WaitToDie() do?

Comment: @mm8 as the name states, it basically prevents the `Program.Main()` method from exiting.  Sleeps for a few seconds, looks around, goes back to sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you remove your custom Main method and move your code to the `App.xaml.cs` class's `OnStartup` method:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        SetupSystemTrayIcon();

        var showConsole = args.Any(x => x.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("showconsole"));
        StartService(showConsole);
    }
}
```

Make sure that the `StartupUri` property is set to `MainWindow.xaml` in your `App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp2.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then you should get a dispatcher and a window that gets activated.

Comment: Yup, that did it.  I wasn't clear on how the App class worked, so I avoided it and tried to stick with console style like I'm used to.  That appears to be the problem.